# iCloud Photos: How to delete all images except images in one album

Tags: ios, icloud, album

I'm looking for a way to delete all images in iCloud Photos, except some that are in one album. Another way to say this is that I want to erase everything, but protect some images from being deleted.

**Is there a way to do this?**

One **workaround** I've found so far is to select the images in the album that one wants to protect from deletion and *hide* them, then delete all other pictures and at last unhide the hidden/protected images again. The previously hidden images will then show up in the album(s) where they were before being hidden. This can't be done on iCloud Photos on the web since I haven't found a way to hide images there. It works on iOS however.